# umbraco one site different brands

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I'm very new to Umbraco and have a requirement to set up a site where different customers will access the same site, but see it with their own brand. It must be the same site in IIS and re-using the same razor views and related code, but our business teams have a requirement to set up a new customer for the same site, with their own values for the configurable content data via Umbraco without relying on support or developer involvement.

eg. Site URL is www.mysite.com

Customer from ClientA visits (maybe via URL www.mysite.com/ClientA or perhaps www.mysite.com?brand=ClientA) and sees the version branded for them.

A customer from ClientB should be able to visit the same site but passing in their brand code instead and see their customized version.

My first question is: Is this acheivable? If so, what is the correct way to do it?

I want to maximise code re-use.

Any help or pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this is standard asp.net, add a code behind for the standard default.aspx page that umbraco uses to drive everything and then in the onpreinit event switch either the master page or theme to the correct branding; something like:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnPreInit(e);

  int templateId = umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent().template;
  umbraco.template template = new umbraco.template(templateId);
  string templateName = template.TemplateAlias;

  if (Request.QueryString["brand"] = "ClientA")
  {
    Page.MasterPageFile = string.format("~/MasterPages/clienta/{0}.master", templateName);
  } 
}
```

So all content is tagged to the standard set of masterpages in the masterpages folder; but if a "?brand=ClientA" url is requested it automatically changes the masterpage to the clienta folder - allowing you to brand the page based on the querystring.

Comment: Thanks. This was the conclusion I'd come to (since putting the question on here) by running through all the options, but I wanted to know from someone with more experience of Umbraco whether it was the right way to go about it. I have more confidence that this is the correct approach now.